# How to move files and folders using google drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google drive API to carry out simple tasks like

1. Moving files across folders.
2. List item

Moving folders.

As far as I could find Google drive API does not provide a way to move files across folders.

With /parent and /children API parent folder of a file can be specified but it does not work for a folder. Moreover the parent attribute associated with a file does not move it under that folder. It just associates a parent attribute with the file(which is not at all useful for my case)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To move FILE-A from FOLDER-1 to FOLDER-2, you can use the delete and add calls at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents to remove FOLDER-1 as a parent and add FOLDER-2.

You can also do a Patch on the file with the updated parents array.

Comment: thanks a lot..I was using the add parent option but was removing the old parent from the parents[].

Comment: patch the parents field in a file used to work but now it's not working anymore. Too bad as it was a one step method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 39):

Drive API V3 has this:

> **Moving files between folders**
>
> To add or remove parents for an existing file, use the `addParents` and `removeParents` query parameters on the files.update method.
>
> Both parameters may be used to move a file from one folder to another:
> https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder

Comment: This should be made the accepted answer. The current accepted answer relates a previous version of the API.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the one step method to move file to the new folder using [Patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) and the [PHP client library](https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads):

```
/**
 * Move a file.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to move.
 * @param string $newParentId Id of the folder to move to.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The updated file. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function moveFile($service, $fileId, $newParentId) {
  try {
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($newParentId);

    $file->setParents(array($parent));

    $updatedFile = $service->files->patch($fileId, $file);

    return $updatedFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

**Update:** If you want to use Drive API v3, use below code [documented here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#moving_files_between_folders):

```
/**
 * Move a file.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to move.
 * @param string $newParentId Id of the folder to move to.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The updated file. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function moveFile($service, $fileId, $newParentId) {
  try {

    $emptyFileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    // Retrieve the existing parents to remove
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId, array('fields' => 'parents'));
    $previousParents = join(',', $file->parents);
    // Move the file to the new folder
    $file = $service->files->update($fileId, $emptyFileMetadata, array(
      'addParents' => $newParentId,
      'removeParents' => $previousParents,
      'fields' => 'id, parents'));

    return $file;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was getting crazy cause it seems that you need to use a new file and not an existing one when using the update method. How's that???

Answer (score 4):

You can actually still do it in one step really just set the request as so in Javascript:

Body must have:

```
body.parents = [{ 'id': parentId }];
```

Request should be:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
  'path': 'drive/v2/files/'+fileId,
  'method': 'PUT',
  'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'}, 
  'headers': { 
    'Authorization': TOKEN
  },
  'body': body
});
```

And then to execute:

```
request.execute(function(resp) { });
```

Comment: I should note, this is what I utilize to move a file or folder and re-associate a new parent to it without having to remove first and then append the new parent after. This works for me and does it all in one step.

Comment: I'm trying to construct the http request whithout any api client.  What api method are you using in this code? I want to test it in the Oaut2 Playground web of google in order to code my own api client for Python3

Comment: Because I am doing a PUT, it's basically just an update. Closest API method to that would be: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Answer (score 2):

This sample code uses Google Drive API v3.

Gfk = Google File Key ( can be the id of either a file or a folder ).

Methods:

- **moveTo** | Moves a file/folder from its first parent folder to a given destination folder. The file/folder gets removed from its original first parent folder;
- **addParents** and **removeParents** | Only adds or removes one or move parents. **addParents** does NOT remove any original parent, only adds.

```php
class Gfiles {
    private $service;

    public function setService(\Google_Client $client) : self {
        $this->service = (new \Google_Service_Drive($client))->files;
        return $this;
    }

    public function moveTo(string $gfk, string $to_gfk) : \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile {
        $body = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        // Gets the first parent. You should further implement this if you wish a different behaviour.
        $from_gfk = $this->service->get($gfk, ['fields' => 'parents'])->parents[0];

        $this->service->update($gfk, $body, ['addParents' => $to_gfk]);
        $this->service->update($gfk, $body, ['removeParents' => $from_gfk]);
        return $this->service->get($gfk, ['fields' => 'parents']);
    }

    /**
     * $parents_gfk expects an array like ['gfk parent 1', 'gfk parent 2'].
     */
    private function updateParents(string $method, string $gfk, array $parents_gfk) : \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile {
        $body = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $parents = join(',', $parents_gfk);

        $this->service->update($gfk, $body, [$method => $parents]);
        return $this->service->get($gfk, ['fields' => 'parents']);
    }

    public function addParents(string $gfk, array $parents_gfk) : \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile {
        return $this->updateParents('addParents', $gfk, $parents_gfk);
    }

    public function removeParents(string $gfk, array $parents_gfk) : \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile {
        return $this->updateParents('removeParents', $gfk, $parents_gfk);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do addParents and removeParents in one call to update, no need to invoke it twice

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code:

```
        File file =  driveService.files().get(fileId).execute()
        File targetFolder = driveService.files().get(folderId).execute()
        ParentReference newParent = new ParentReference()
        newParent.setSelfLink(targetFolder.getSelfLink())
        newParent.setParentLink(targetFolder.parents[0].getSelfLink())
        newParent.setId(folderId)
        newParent.setKind(targetFolder.getKind())
        newParent.setIsRoot(false)
        def parentsList = new ArrayList<ParentReference>()
        parentsList.add(newParent)
        file.setParents(parentsList)
        File updatedFile = driveService.files().update(fileId, file).execute()
```

Comment: This code does not execute as written. I'm going to submit an update to it.