# Create google API creds for Gmail account not service account

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-api-php-client

i have a code that uses creates a google document:

```
    public function create_content_document(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $contentId = $data['id'];

        // Convert HTML to plain text
        $textContent = $data['text'];

        // Create a new Google Document
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('name');
        $client->setScopes([
            Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS,
            Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
        ]);
        $credentialsPath = storage_path('service account creds.json');
        // for debugging dd the content of the file


        $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsPath);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        $service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);

        // Create a new empty document with a title
        $document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document([
            'title' => "title",
        ]);
        $createdDocument = $service->documents->create($document);

        // Get the document ID
        $documentId = $createdDocument->documentId;

        // Save the document link on the content
        $documentLink = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/{$documentId}";

        // Set sharing settings to anyone with the link
        $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
        $newPermission->setType('anyone');
        $newPermission->setRole('writer');
        $driveService->permissions->create($documentId, $newPermission);

        // Update the document content
        $service->documents->batchUpdate(
            $documentId,
            new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest([
                'requests' => [
                    'insertText' => [
                        'location' => ['index' => 1],
                        'text' => $textContent,
                    ],
                ],
            ])
        );

        // Redirect or return the document link as needed
        return $documentLink;
    }
```

this creates the doc and saves it, but its owned by the service account, soon i want to make it so its saved in a drive folder, bun that would also mean that it'll be the service accounts folder.

so the plan is to dispose of the service account and add creds for my gmail account and have the docs appear in my drive directly.

this solution seems to be easy, just replace the service account json creds file with my own accounts json creds file, but i dont know where to generate that from.

[creds screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h0Cb.png)
i tried creating a `OAuth 2.0 Client` key, and it seems to download a json file, but its not the same format as the service account, and it doesnt work when i add it, i get auth error.

so i guess my question is either, how to create creds for the my gmail account directly and use them to create docs sheets and drive folders, or if not available is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: `i dont know where to generate that from`... as far as I know you can't. You'd have to actually log in via the UI, and then pass the login token to PHP to use in the request to Google. Service accounts are the way you avoid that. Surely you can make it save into a different folder in Drive? The service account, if it's comes under your google account anyway, should be able to be given permission to save to the place you want.

Comment: can the different folder be owned by another account? would it need permission and stuff?
edit: yes it can sorry, just add the service email to the permissions list.

but what about creating a folder thru a service account for another account, is that possible?

Comment: I'd expect so, again if the service account has permission to the parent folder. Try it and see

Comment: @ADyson can you lend me some resources to help with uploading the doc to a specific folder, or should i ask another question?

Comment: I think you have to upload it and then move it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881130/5947043

Comment: thanks, i reached my end goal without doing what i originally asked for (create creds for gmail account), do you recommend deleting the question or just leaving it.

Comment: Well if you think your alternative solution might be useful to other people you could add it as an Answer, below